# standard file to place fonts and other styles

Tags: objective-c

I would like to #define all my fonts and colors for my app in one file for iphone project.  What is the standard approach for this?  Do most people just create a .h file and place the defines in there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most common approach is to define them in a Utils class.